# Callbacks over Callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, extjs

I want to put markers on a map. The source is a json request, which returns cities.

I've got a function (sencha) that returns the records (asynchronous) and a function (google maps api) that returns the lng, lat for specific cities  (asynchronous)  and a method (google maps), that puts markers on the map.

The result should be a marker on the map at the location calculated by google with a caption retrieved from the record.

load records

```
offers = App.stores.offers.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success){...}
})
```

get location

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(
  {'address': adress},
  function(results, status) {...}
}
```

and set the marker

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: loc,
  title: text
});
```

What I wan't to do is, load the record, loop over each record, find out about location of the city and put a marker there.

synchronous I would do:

```
   records = App.stores.offers.load();
   for (var i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
     setMarker( map, getLocation(records[i].data["city"]), cords[i].data["text"]);
   }
```

What's the right way to put it together with the asynchronous functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what does the App.stores.offers.load function do exactly but I'll assume its callback function arguments contain loading results in records variable. In this case loop through records inside callback function and for each call geocode, and on geocode's callback place markers (nothing wrong with this).

EDIT: this is untested and probably not most efficient but should work:

```
offers = App.stores.offers.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        if (success) {//or sth like this
            var complete;
            for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                complete = false;
                geocoder.geocode( {'address': records[i].adress},
                  function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            title: results[i].text,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                    complete = true;
                });
                while (!complete);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually that was my first guess too, but if I need the the text from records[i].text to set the markers title, this won't work..

Comment: you weren't very clear on what you need, I'll try to figure sth out

Comment: Why should results[i] store the text? Because it's asynchronous "i" is in the callback of "geocode" not what you expect it to be, most probably it's records.length, because the loop is (a lot) faster than getting the response from google back.

Comment: that's why while loop prevents the for loop from moving on until response from geocode is processed, in theory at least:-)

Comment: but I forgot to set 'complete' flag to false in for loop, editing now

Comment: I see your intension. I think it'll work in theory. It also blocks the app until the response is received, which is not always the behavior you want. I will post the code I used in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented it with extjs / sencha. The second problem I run in to was the restrictions on the google maps service (I had a lot of quota exceeded exceptions). So it's not exactly the answer to the question. So I marked the other answer as correct, because it's closer to the question. Here the code I had in the end anyway, may it help someone.

```
App.stores.offers = new Ext.data.Store({
 model: 'Offer',
(...)

 listeners: {
  load: function(store, records, success){
  this.addEvents( "refresh_locations", "locations_updated" );
  for (var i=0; i < store.data.length; i++) {
    store.fireEvent("refresh_locations", store , store.getAt(i), "load" );
  }
 },
refresh_locations: function(store, record, method){
  if (record.get("location")  == null || record.get("location") == ""){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'api/partner2sport/find_location', 
      params: {
        "city" : record.get("place")
      },
      success: function(response, options) { 
        db_check = Ext.decode(response.responseText)["success"];
        if (db_check){
          var latlngStr = Ext.decode(response.responseText)["location"].replace(/\(|\)/g,"").split(",",2)
          var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]) - (Math.random() / 100);
          var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) - (Math.random() / 100);
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
          record.set("location", latlng);
        }else{
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode(
            {
                'address': record.get("place")
            },
            function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {              
                record.set("location", results[0].geometry.location);
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                  url: 'api/partner2sport/set_location', 
                  params: {
                    "city" : record.get("place"),
                    "location": record.get("location")
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          );
        }
      },
      failure: function(response, options) { 
        console.log("bad request");
      }
    });
  }
},
```

(...)

Comment: and how do you verify which location geocoding result have you received?